# Are there tools or metrics that measure the complexity of a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, code-metrics

I am aware of tools that use static analysis to measure the complexity of code written in a single language, e.g., Java.  Application frameworks like Spring make measurement of complexity more difficult - many of the interactions are not readily apparent, and they may span several technologies (e.g., Java, JSP, XML).  For example, XML files might indicate dependencies.  Are there any tools that one can use to determine the relative complexity of a Spring application?

I am especially interested in coupling as a measure of complexity; however, I would like to hear about any complexity metrics/tools that might be applicable.